# How to find the distance between two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have two convergent real-valued sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ converging to the same limit say $l,$ then how do we define the notion of a distance between these two sequences. I was thinking of using the usual metric and say that $d = |a_n-b_n|$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N},$ but I am not sure whether this is the best way to go forward with this problem. Any ideas or similar definitions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Presumably $|a_n-b_n|$ is not a constant.  In the limit, of course $a_n-b_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard way to do it. Since the sequences have the same limit you  have $|a_n - b_n| \to 0$ so that $d = \max_n |a_n - b_n|$ exists and is finite. This is one way to define the distance between the sequences, but you should probably show that it satisfies the axioms of a metric.

Comment: Why does the max exist?

Comment: What would happen if it didn't?

Comment: You would have written $\sup$ instead of $\max$ and $d = \sup |a_n-b_n|$, right?

Comment: Of course, but the supremum is obtained.

Comment: Because the sequence is convergent, right?